# How do I do fullScreenIntent from FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to show a full-screen activity on the lock screen when the app recieves a firebase cloud message.

Currently the code looks like this:

```
 private void showFullScreenIntent(RemoteMessage remoteMessage, String ticketNumber) {
        try {
            int acceptCallRequestCode = 0;

            String channelId = getString(R.string.channel_id);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_name)
                    .setContentTitle("Incoming Video Conference Call")
                    .setContentText("From Demo Doctor")
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setFullScreenIntent(createAcceptCallIntent(remoteMessage, acceptCallRequestCode), true);

            // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
            int notificationId = GlobalState.getInstance().getNewNotificationId();
            Log.d(TAG, "showFullScreenIntent NotificationId: " + notificationId);
            //https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive
            // Provide a unique integer for the "notificationId" of each notification.
            startForeground(notificationId, builder.build());

            Log.d(TAG, "Finished showFullScreenIntent");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }


    }

    private PendingIntent createAcceptCallIntent(RemoteMessage remoteMessage, int requestCode) {
        // Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, remoteMessage);

        //Create hashmap of extra stuff
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(LAUNCH_METHOD, "notification");
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_MAP, map);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        return pendingIntent;
    }
```

The logs show that there are no errors and I can see that Finished showFullScreenIntent gets output to the log. Also the notification id is greater than zero.

My manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.augustinus.fcmtest">

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">

        <!-- Add this SplashActivity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Remove the intent-filter of the MainActivity and add a param android:exported="true" -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
        <service
            android:name=".CustomFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

</manifest>
```